# Unity Event after Layout update but before OnWillRenderObject()

Tags: unity, gui

Looking for subscribe-able event that occurs right after Layout update in Unity but before OnWillRenderObject is called.

Working solution is Canvas.willRenderCanvases, but useful to know if more events exist before or after this event:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-willRenderCanvases.html

Here is picture in-case unfamiliar with Unity Layout update:

[image]

Comment: +1 for your Canvas.willRenderCanvases solution. I don't think there is a post-Layout Update event, unfortunately, but this workaround is sufficient for my use case.